# flutter create takes long time to create the project

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a flutter app but it doesn't work I still loading and nothing happens.

I've also tried flutter upgrade and other flutter options

Comment: Why is there an empty code field in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using laptop of 4 GB RAM and not having the processor like Intel core i5,i3,5 or 8 generation than it will take long time than usually but it will work you have to be patient.